# Custom cls and sty not found

Tags: pdftex

When trying to compile my document with custom cls and sty files, I'm getting this error message (for four files in total):

```
! LaTeX Error: File `filename.cls' not found.
```

Using pdflatex I can enter the path and filename and the document gets compiled without errors.
I put the files in ~/texmf/latex/tex/mais/

I tried setting the previously empty TEXINPUTS which did not work:

```
export TEXINPUTS=/home/chris/texmf/latex/tex/mais/:${TEXINPUTS}
```

I also created a symlink in /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex to above directory.

Where do I need to put my custom files for LaTeX to work? I use it at the office all the time but at home I just messed up something and can't use it here.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with texlive 2016

Comment: Have you renewed your file-name-database?

Comment: Can you tell what's the output of the command line `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`? Also, the path should better be `/home/chris/texmf/tex/latex/mais` (rename the folders).

Comment: filename.cls? That is even worse than thesis.cls

Comment: kpsewhich has an emtpy output, however, the wrong path was actually the issue! Thank you! filename.cls isn't actually the filename ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error consists in the wrong names: change

```
/home/chris/texmf/latex/tex/mais/
```

Into

```
/home/chris/texmf/tex/latex/mais/
```

Comment: Accepted the answer, thanks again for your help. Such a minor mistake, I didn't even think to look there.